# Can U use the middleware the same way in the controller or route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to make sure that you can't just type /admin into the top bar. I made an extra column in the user table called `admin` and it's either `0` (normal user) or `1` (admin).

In the blade page, I'm checking:

```
@if (Auth::check())
  @if (Auth::user()->admin == 1)
   <p>Hello Admin</p>
  @else
   <p>Hello standard user</p>
  @endif
@endif
```

I was asking if it's possible to either check in the route (**something like this**)

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('auth')-where('admin' 1);
```

or in the controller (**something like this**)

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth')->where('admin' 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a new middleware.

First create a new middleware by typing in your console:

`php artisan make:middleware isAdmin`

Name your middleware whatever you like, isAdmin is common here.

Next you must add the middleware to your Kernel.php located at app/Http/Kernel.php, edit the array named `$routeMiddleware` and add the following:

`'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,`

Open your IsAdmin.php located in your middleware folder and modify the handle method like so:

```
{
     if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Note: the middleware will also check if a user is authenticated so could be used in place of auth for admin routes, remember to modify the return to suit your needs**

Lastly, add the middleware to your route, there are a number of ways to do this.

- if you are planning to use it instead of auth middleware, simple change auth to isAdmin in your routes file `->middleware('isAdmin')`
- Another option is to modify your routes file like so

```
Route::group(['middleware => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('isAdmin');
}
```

So you don't need to apply the middlewares to each route, there are a bunch of possibilities for this here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes